# Adding testers using iTunesConnect TestFlight

Tags: ios, air, testflight

I have been developing apps for iOS using Adobe Air SDK and have been using testflightapp.com for adding testers. But now that testflightapp.com has been moved, I am having issues adding testers through iTunesConnect test flight.
I upload the app to iTunesConnect using Application loader app.

But even after uploading the app, I am not able to invite testers. Also the provisioning profile is a newly created so it should be with beta entitlement.

[image: App in prerelease with a warning symbol next to build number]

In the build details the Internal Testing and External Testing is in processing state for more than 3 days.

[image: Internal and External testing in processing state]

iTunesConnect does not show any errors/warning for this build. What should I do to invite testers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you followed these instructions for setting up your app descriptor xml correctly?

http://www.flashdeveloper.co/post/99200413877/enabling-testflight-testing-in-itunes-connect-for

Comment: Thanks for the link. I haven't done this and I think this would work. Currently I am stuck with getting the iOS SDK. Will update once I try it.

Answer (score 1):

Use following link to do that-

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://fastchicken.co.nz/2014/11/05/using-apples-new-testflight-beta-testing/) that explains everything in simple words.It was really helpful to me.

Hope this helps